# PowerShell Script error :Underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

I need to Post a json content to an API url using a token. But it showing me the error *Underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for SSL/TLS secure channel

My Code is below

```
$header = @{
   'Accept' = 'Application/json'
   'Çontent-Type' = 'application/json'
   'Authorization' = 'Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
}

$examdetails=@{
    "extra_vars" = @{
      "input" = "passed candidate name"
    }
}

$params = @{
 'Method'= 'Post'
 'Uri' = 'https://example.xxxx/api/45213/launch'
  'Headers'= $headers
 'Body'= (convertto-json $examdetails)
}

$submissionofcandidate = Invoke-RestMethod @params
```

The above code showing me the error Underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for SSL/TLS secure channel. Could someone help me to sort it? And also help me with how can I convert the Authorization token to secure string and use it in this code.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the below error:

> Underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for SSL/TLS secure channel.

You may need to check if there are any proxy / firewall within your corporate network. If yes, does it use self-signed certificate or any specific TLS version ?

You could leverage the below sample script to achieve your requirement:

```
$endpointUrl = "https://example.com/api/endpoint"
$accessToken = "eyjiwenervbjevgabcdefg123xyzXXXXXXXXXXXX"

# Create the JSON body for the request
$jsonBody = @{
    "name" = "peter max"
    "email" = "petermax@contoso.com"
} | ConvertTo-Json

# Create the headers for the request
$headers = @{
    "Authorization" = "Bearer $accessToken"
    "Content-Type" = "application/json"
}

# Make the POST request with the JSON body and headers
# If you want to use higher TLS version then you can uncomment the below line. The accepted values are: Tls12, Tls11  and Tls:
# [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $endpointUrl -Method Post -Body $jsonBody -Headers $headers

# Display the response content
$response.Content
```

Please note, If the above script also fails with the same error (Could not establish trust relationship for SSL/TLS secure channel) the issue is on your network side in establishing a secure SSL/TLS connection. You can test from a different network and check if that works. Hope this helps.